# jackson mixins throwing stackoverflow error

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

Hi I'm writing a Rest service for a user object retrieved from common framework of my company.

**User userobj = commonframework.getuser(userid);** //user is interface

The problem is the user object from common framework has an object with 2 getters for a String field like "isSomeflag()" and "getSomeflag()"
*I cannot modify the code from commonframework*

I ended up using ** Jackson Mixins** but it is throwing stackoverflow error. Any help will be appreciated.

**Code below**

```
    public abstract class IgnoreMixin {
    @JsonIgnore 
    public abstract String isServiceOnlyflg();
}
```

**In service method:**

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createUserInfo{
mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(DealerImpl.class,IgnoreMixin.class);
writer = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
return writer.writeValueAsString(userobj);
}
```

**Approach -2**

I tried creating local class with similar property and try mapping those properties from user object to local object. 
*inital inference the problem class is referenced only once in user object*

But The problem is user contains many member object which in turn refer the problem object many times and I have to create many local copy of many classes from  framework user structure

Any solution for this

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoring to the documentation if the method in your base class are
`isSomeflag()` and `getSomeflag()` . You should use

```
 @JsonProperty("newProp") abstract int isSomeflag()
 @JsonIgnore abstract int getSomeflag();
```

Ignore one and let the other be marshall with the JsonProperty.

Also probably you are within a circular dependency that you need to break with jsonfilter, check this [link](http://www.theotherian.com/2014/02/jackson-mixins-and-modules-external-classes.html)

```
 FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
      .addFilter("filtermixin", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("circulardependency"));
```